# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in nano?

Tags: command-line, nano

To indent a whole block of code in nano, after selecting it with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I have to press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>, which doesn't work on my german layout macintosh keyboard (and would be pretty annoying even if it did).

How do I change and customize nano's keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file `/etc/nanorc` contains some options that should allow you to customize the shortcuts used on the editor. Please note that this is a global config file and will modify the options for all users on your system.

Further details on the available options are given on the [`man nanorc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/nanorc.5.html) page (the list is just too big to reproduce here):

[image]

It should be possible to keep the options localized only to your user by copying the system configuration file in to your user's home directory with

```
cp /etc/nanorc ~/.nanorc
```

and doing the modifications necessary there.

The configuration file on your home directory will prevail over the global settings one.

Comment: For the issue of changing this only for the local user is there any way around this? (Want to change keybindings on a cluster. No root privileges can only install in my own folders. Should I create my own nano build and alter the path/ use an alias in order to use my own instead of the standard one.)

Comment: Would it be possible to change keybinding for page down to `M-v`?

Comment: @Kvothe you can put your settings in ~/.config/nano/nanorc

Answer (score 9):

The following has been tested using nano from a terminal in MS-Windows.
It will get your **nano** one step closer supporting the "universal" shortcuts for copy/cut/paste etc. (at least in the Windows world).
Add these lines to the file `/etc/nanorc`

```
bind ^c copytext main
bind ^x cut main
bind ^v uncut main
bind ^z undo main
bind ^y redo main
bind ^f whereis main
bind F3 findnext main
bind ^h replace main
set tabsize 4
set linenumbers
```

Be aware they work per whole-line if you don't select text first :-/

If you have issues selecting text in **nano** with `shift+arrow-keys` then be aware this doesn't seem to be related to **nano** but your terminal program! It doesn't work in PuTTY, but it does e.g. work in Kitty (a fork of PuTTY, [Windows-version](http://www.9bis.net/kitty) / [Linux-version](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty)) or Google's SSH client for Chrome.

(I'm using Debian buster)

Comment: Also: `bind ^s writeout main`

Comment: Getting the error: `Error in ~.nanorc on line 326: Could not map name "findnext" to a function

Error in ~.nanorc on line 329: Unknown flag "linenumbers"`

Comment: Where do  I find a list of available shortcuts to set? Is there version dependences and resources for these different versions?

Comment: There is a list of keybindings [here](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nanorc.5.html#KEY%20BINDINGS)

Comment: Great but then how do you quit out of Nano if you reassigned ^X?

Comment: You should be able to see that in the menu at the bottom of the screen, it will probably change to F2

Comment: @mrcalvin I'm getting errors for 2 key bindings, `bind ^c copytext main` and `bind ^v uncut main`, in Ubuntu MATE 21.04. Errors: `Error in /home/admn/.nanorc on line 1: Cannot map name "copytext" to a function` and `Error in /home/admn/.nanorc on line 2: Cannot map name "uncut" to a function`. Any idea on how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: @Jags the linked documentation is outdated, try [this](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v5/nanorc.5.html). `copytext` is now just `copy` for example.

Comment: The keybinding keywords differ, depending on which version of nano you are using.  Try `nano --version`, and then use the link provided by @MrCalvin.  Change the version in the address bar to match the nano version you are using and reload the web page.