# Nano editor shortcuts mind bending

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, nano

**Intro:**

As for beginner, i was choosing between text editors, and stopped on nano (cause work with it will make my terminal skills better. I hope.)

**Problem:**

As the first thing I'm facing up with nano is shortcuts. I mean they are **extremely** not intuitive (if i had even 5 tries for one shortcut - i will never guess the right one) and not comfortable (as example: `Alt+U`, `Alt+E` is undo, redo correspondingly, but `U` and `E` not even next keys on keyboard). 
And as result i was going to amend them (like [so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235664/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nano)), but next thing comes to my mind was - **this may be against** of my aim to learn CLI.

**Question:**

Are the nano shortcuts "standard"? Are they used in other programs? Will learning them help me use other CLI tools or are they specific to nano?

Comment: I edited your question so it doesn't read like a request for opinion (which is not on topic here). I hope I kept the spirit of your question, please let me know if I did not.

Comment: Those are what the makers of the program found intuitive. I do not think. (I don't  think computers or computer programs can be intuitive in a way that is remotely objective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only recurring concepts of command-line text editors I know of are those of `vi`/`vim` and `emacs`, e.g. the *Vi style command mode with tab completion* in [`cmus`](https://cmus.github.io/#features). I guess that's because those two are the two main competitors in this field (see [the WP article about the Editor war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)) and both are around long enough to influence other software. If you *really* want to dive into command-line usage, I suggest you learn to use one of those two – both are so much more then just editors, it's really worth the time and effort. Personally, I rarely use `nano` at all, and then only for *very* simple editing tasks.

Note however that [`ed` is the standard text editor](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html) and [real programmers use butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Real programmers use butterflies is intended to be an arcane reference to nano iinm because many species of butterflies have delicate nanostructures in their wings that create their beautiful pigmentation by interacting with light.

Comment: @karel I think it rather refers to the [Butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect), but that's a discussion better suited for http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/378. :)

Comment: So ... text editor. For now, If this the only case,  it looks like 'pick editor -> change shortcuts as you like -> profit'. The only case of hassle with defaults, as i can devise for now, is the ability to use them naturally in alien environment.

Answer (score 3):

The following has been tested using nano from a terminal in MS-Windows.
It will get your **nano** one step closer supporting the "universal" shortcuts for copy/cut/paste etc. (at least in the Windows world).
Add these lines to the nano configfile `/etc/nanorc`

```
bind ^c copy main
bind ^v paste all
bind ^x cut main
bind ^z undo main
bind ^y redo main
bind ^f whereis main
bind F3 findnext main
bind ^h replace main
set zap
set tabsize 4
#set linenumbers
```

Notes:

- `set zap` will change the behavior of DELETE and BACKSPACE to what a normal windows user expect i.e. the selected text will be deleted, which is not the default behavior.
- `copy` and `cut` behave rather strange. If you haven't selected any text it will copy/cut the whole line!
- If your nano version is < 3.00 then you have to use `copytext` instead of `copy` and `uncut` instead of `paste`. RHELish distros (RHEL, CentOS, Oracle Linux) still use the old version (as per 20 september 2020).

If you have issues selecting text in **nano** with `shift+arrow-keys` then be aware this doesn't seem to be related to **nano** but your terminal program.
In my case it didn't work in PuTTY, but it did work in Kitty (a fork of PuTTY, [Windows-version](http://www.9bis.net/kitty) / [Linux-version](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty)).

Comment: Joined this community just to upvote you. thank you!

Comment: How does this work with using nano on a cluster where it is preinstalled and you only want to affect yourself and not other users. Is there a way to create the nanorc file in some directory and make nano use that one (for that user)?

Comment: I think so in your home folder....try to search for it or look in the manual. I cannot remember the details

Answer (score 2):

Within nano, the most common keyboard shortcuts are displayed at the bottom of the terminal window for your reference.  This means there is no need for you to intentionally memorize them, or to stress over knowing them.

The more you use any text editor, the more comfortable you will become and the easier it will be to make changes quickly and efficiently.

Here is an overview document to help you learn nano:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/

I don't recommend changing the nano default key bindings (shortcuts) but you can if you want by editing the nanorc file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nanorc
```

You can learn about the contents of the nanorc file within its corresponding man page:

```
man nanorc
```

Learning to use the terminal is about more than just using a text editor.  It's about becoming comfortable using the keyboard to interact with and change a system.  It's about learning to navigate the directories, and about using commands to quickly find and execute what you want to do.

Like many things, it's a process, and any time you spend using the terminal (or linux in general) will help you improve.

Comment: Agree with everything, except memorizing - i need to do it (it's just the term of effective using). But as i agree, at the same time i don't see any answer on my question - are this shortcuts applicable anywhere else or not? Only recommendation - 'don't recommend changing'.

Comment: @SergeiShorokhov rebind them to what you consider useful? `cp /etc/nanorc ~/.nanorc` and edit away ;-)